# Testing ModelSerializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to learn the best way to test my serializers but having some issues. In the below example I am testing to see if creating new users works correctly. ie can hash the password. The error i am getting is:

> TypeError: create() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'validated_data'

Im not really sure what I need to pass in as `validated_data`

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'view_name': 'user-detail'},
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email'])

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.get(id=instance.id)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user
```

tests.py

```
class UserSerializerTest(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):

        factory = APIRequestFactory()

        request = factory.get(path=reverse('user-list'))

        self.serializer_context = {
            'request': Request(request),
        }

    def test_create_user(self):
        from .serializers import UserSerializer

        data = {'username': 'temp_usr', 'email': 'temp@email.com',
                'password': 'temp_pass'}

        user = UserSerializer(data=data, context=self.serializer_context).create()
```

Comment: Because it's required by method definition :). Is there a specific reason why you're testing the serializer itself and not the whole create view?

Answer (score 1):

You called `create` in your test. You should call `is_valid` and then `save`.

```
user = UserSerializer(data=data, context=self.serializer_context)
user.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
user.save()
```